# Vim map for C/C++ case statements

Tags: c++, c, vim

I want to create a mapping in Vim for the following scenario:

`case blah:` -->

hit enter -->

```
case blah:{

}break;
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
inoremap case<Space><expression>:<CR> case<Space><expression>:{<CR>}break;<Esc>ko
```

But I don't know what to put for "expression".  What would I put there?  Is it more complicated than this?
Thanks!

Comment: [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe), [SnipMate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate), [Neosnippet](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim), [XPTemplate](https://github.com/drmingdrmer/xptemplate)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at my switch and case snippets for [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template)/[lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp), and the switch generator from an enum. Either the case is automatically filled from an enum, or I use a placeholder you can then jump to.

Otherwise, the ideal (simple) solution would be to map enter and detect that the context is `case\s\+\S\+:\s*`. In that case you could insert `{\n}\nbreak;\<up>\<up>\<c-f>`. But this mapping may also have to recognize enter from within a pair of `{}` and so on.